# Cut specific string from mysql field and update same field with the string

Tags: mysql, regex

i am looking for an option to update an existing field in mysql table, where title says

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| title                                                               | albumid |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------|
| a:1:{s:5:"en_US";s:11:"Donau river";}                               |     171 |
| a:1:{s:5:"en_US";s:26:"The Sunset of River Danube";}                |     171 |
| a:1:{s:5:"en_US";s:26:"quiet evening at the river";}                |     171 |
| a:1:{s:5:"en_US";s:20:"river beach interior";}                      |     171 |
| a:1:{s:5:"en_US";s:41:"A quiet evening on the beach at the river";} |     171 |
```

want to trim the title field e.g.

from

a:1:{s:5:"en_US";s:11:"Donau river";}

to

Donau river

And Update the mysql field at the same time with this new value?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UPDATE yourTable 
SET title = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(title,'";}',1),':"',-1);
```